# Preview Word File instead of downloading in the browser using PHPWord in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpword, phpoffice

I want to preview created new Word file in a browser using **PHPWord** in **Laravel**

I have successfully managed to make a word file but now I want to preview it instead of downloading.

I have a system in it I am proving a file when it created. 
PDF and Image files are working fine. But the Word file is not getting preview in the browser.

Here is the function

```
public function saveAndPreviewDocx()
{
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();

    $description_data = "This is a sample text and i want it to preview this in a browser in word file";       
    $section->addText($description_data);

    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
    try {
        $objWriter->save(storage_path('new_doc12.docx'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }
 // How can i view the file in the browser form here or form the view using the phpWord

}
```

This function is creating a file but I want to preview the created file in the browser.

in a way of finding a solution, I found that I can view word files using google Docs view or Microsoft office view but they are not useful to me because I have a private server.

I Have tried the **Google Docs Viewer** & **Microsoft Office Viewer** but in my private server it's not working.

So I want any clean solution to solve this word preview in the web browser as we see other files like PDF and all.